# PermissionError: [WinError 32] for GridSearchCV in spyder

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
param_test1 = {'n_estimators':range(20,81,10)}
gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator = GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, 
                                                               min_samples_split=500,
                                                               min_samples_leaf=50,
                                                               max_depth=8,
                                                               max_features='sqrt',
                                                               subsample=0.8,
                                                               random_state=10), 
                                                  param_grid = param_test1, 
                                                               scoring='roc_auc',
                                                               n_jobs=4,
                                                               iid=False, 
                                                               cv=5)


gsearch1.fit(train[predictors],train[target]) #getting error on this line
```

> Error:PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the
>   file because it is being used by another process:
>   'C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Temp\joblib_memmapping_folder_xx\xx-xx-xx.pkl'

`Windows 10
Python 3.6.4
sklearn.__version__
Out[26]: '0.20.2'`

Please let me know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a common problem.
Googling the error (which is always good practice :-) ) led [here](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/806), where they offer this workaround:

> Thanks for the details. For now I'm using Parallel with `max_nbytes=None`

Comment: I went through many of the comments on google related to this error. but i am not able to understand what exactly i should change in the above code to avoid this error.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to start an instance of `Parallel` before running it, and setting that instance with `max_nbytes=None` (if you have enough memory...)